# Почему не сообщает о попадании

Tags: c#, .net, unity3d

подскажите почему не пишет в консоль что попал.
вот скрипт `    void Update()
    {

```
    if (kill.EnemyIsDead == false)
    {
        if (hello.stadia == 1)
        {
            transform.LookAt(target);
             Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);//создаем луч первый параметр -откуда будет испускаться ,луч 2- куда
            RaycastHit hit;//сталкнулся ли обьект 

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit ))
            {
                if (hit.collider.name == "personaj")
                {
                    Debug.Log("попал");

                }
                else if (hit.collider.tag == "Untagged")
                {

                }
            }
        }}`
```

Comment: Очень вам советую научится производить отладку приложения. Поставьте в нужных местах точки остановки и посмотрите, какую проверку не проходит и почему...

Comment: @Дело в том что мне почти всегда выдает что не попало ,и только иногда выдает что попал

Comment: @EvgeniyZ   выше  !!1

Comment: После racast поставьте Debug.Log(hit.collider.name);  и посмотрите куда у вас луч попадает.